# Making seaborn.PairGrid() look like pairplot()

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

In the example below, how do I use `seaborn.PairGrid()` to reproduce the plots created by `seaborn.pairplot()`? Specifically, I'd like the diagonal distributions to span the vertical axis. Markers with white borders etc... would be great too. Thanks!

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# pairplot() example
g = sns.pairplot(iris, kind='scatter', diag_kind='kde')
plt.show()

# PairGrid() example
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
plt.show()
```

[image][image]

Comment: The issue is the diagonal data is plotted with a KDE, which has a vertical range of 0 to 1. Then you've overlaid that axis with the scatterplot, which has a different vertical range. Resulting in a plot where the diagonal data doesn't appear correctly plotted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [quite simple](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/v0.10.1/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L1902) to achieve. The main differences between your plot and what `pairplot` does are:

- the use of the `diag_sharey` parameter of `PairGrid`
- using `sns.scatterplot` instead of `plt.scatter`

With that, we have:

```py
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, diag_sharey=False)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To change the visual style:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, shade=True)
g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter, edgecolor="w")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Good to know how much `pairplot()` does under the hood to pretty things up. The reason I am using `PairGrid()` is because it offers flexibility for some other customizations I need to add to my plots.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't correct; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455282/1533576) for an explanation.

Comment: @mwaskom good to know, I edited out the assertion in my answer.

Comment: @mwaskom I am accepting your answer as correct, and thanks everyone for helping me better understand `pairplot()` and `PairGrid()`